# Convert CentOS to Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

**Hi everyone.**
I recently purchased a VPS with CentOS 5.3!

However, I want it to run on Ubuntu. How do I convert the system to Ubuntu?

Comment: This is more appropriate for http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best you can do is to ask system administrators of the company you purchased your VPS from. They may do it manually and backup data on your VPS you may want to save.
This option also might be accessible on the control panel of you VPS provider.
Reinstalling OS by hand on your VPS may result in a lot of headache and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Just install Ubuntu; it doesn't matter what's already installed.

If you have any data on the machine that you care about, back it up first.

Comment: I'll try it. I'm new at Linux, so it might not end well! Haha.